# What's the difference between "type json" and "parse json" in fluentd and what should I use?

Tags: json, parsing, fluentd

I stumbled upon the following two options of parsing json with fluentd:

```
<filter foo.bar>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

and

```
<filter foo.bar>
  @type parser
  format json
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```

Both work, but what is the difference and what should I use? Both take about 30 seconds to process the message ... somehow really long in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i apologize - stupid question - the syntax only has changed between the documentation 1.0 and 0.12... so version 1.0 should be used i think.